# Implementing AnyObject to NSString Issue

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to put AnyObject value to NSString and print it but unfortunatlly it is always crashing without showing the reason just `EXC`. After debugging I found it is crashing after `currStr`. So please where would be my issue?

```
      var lastRefresh: AnyObject = self.currDic["Response"]!.objectForKey("Datasource")!

      self.currStr = lastRefresh as NSString

      println("Data: \(self.curreStr)")
```

My lastRefresh output:

```
{
Cookie = 0nss1w45xzuocyqgvrjcmr31;
Message = "\U0130\U015flem Ba\U015farl\U0131";
Response =     {
    Datasource =         (
                    {
            Content = "";
            Date = "20.01.2015";
            Time = "08:32:22";
            Title = "Example1";
        },
                    {
            Content = "";
            Date = "20.01.2015";
            Time = "08:32:22";
            Title = "Example2";
        },
```

Comment: What is lastRefreshDate? I see you declare a variable lastRefresh, but not lastRefreshDate. Also, why do you print out curreStr, but edit currStr?

Comment: What is the error ? How can you cast to NSMutableString, you should rather cast it to NSString !

Comment: @ad121 I have fix that it is mistakenly written. I'm sorry what do you mean by editing it? I just want to print it.

Comment: You change the value of self.currStr and print self.curreStr. The latter has an extra e in it.

Comment: @k6sandeep I'm not sure what is the error while the comelier doesn't show me that it is just crashing. I have made it NSString.

Comment: Bacause the `lastRefresh` is an array or dictionary. Please post entire `lastRefresh` NSLog not just a part of it

Comment: You cannot cast lastRefresh to NSString, were you trying to extract some key of lastRefresh array ?

Comment: The lastRefresh is very long @MidhunMP and  `pariteDic` is a dictionary. I'm trying to take the `title` value.

Comment: @k6sandeep I'm trying to extract it to  `parser = NSXMLParser(data: self.currStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)) `

Comment: So what is your expected result ?

Comment: So what do you get when parsing the result a dictionary or an array. It is quite unclear looking at the code above, what exactly you were trying to do.

Comment: I have edited my output(currDic) result. I'm trying to get the `Datasource` value from the output into NSString and then I will parse it. I hope this help you.

Comment: But why you need to pass that to NSXMLParser ? Is that key contains any XML ? I'm not seeing any in your above example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments It's clear that, you need to convert the `lastRefresh` object to `NSData` for using it in `NSXMLParser`.

From your `NSLog` it looks like a `Dictionary` or `Array`. You can convert it to data using:

```
var yourData : NSData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(lastRefresh, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: nil)!
```